# Update user profile picture is not working how it should

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have problem with updating user profile picture. After pasting the data into the form and clicking on the submit button it says "change has been made". Everything has been really change except the profile picture. The problem is that the image is not stored in the folder. And I do not know why. Can somebody help me please?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['ulozitzmeny']) && ($_SESSION['user']) && strlen($_SESSION['user']) > 0) {

    $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jmeno']);
    $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prijmeni']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = hash('sha512', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['heslo']));

    $file = rand(1000, 100000) . "-" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder = "images/";
    $new_size = $file_size / 1024;
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $final_file = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);
    move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file);

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='$_SESSION[user]'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $sql = "SELECT file FROM users WHERE username='$_SESSION[user]'";
    $result_set = mysql_query($sql);
    $row2=mysql_fetch_array($result_set);

    if ($password != $row[0]) {

        echo" <div style='position:absolute;left:29.5%;top:10%;width:41%;' class='alert alert-danger fade in'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>Chyba!</strong> NespĂˇvnĂ© heslo!
             </div>";
    } else {

        if (mysql_query("UPDATE users SET first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', email='$email', file='$final_file', type='$file_type', size='$new_size' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user]'")or die(mysql_query)) {

            echo" <div style='position:absolute;left:29.5%;top:10%;width:41%;' class='alert alert-success'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>ĂšspÄ›ch!</strong> ZmÄ›ny probÄ›hly ĂşspÄ›ĹˇnÄ›!               
             </div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Here is my form: http://pastebin.com/wtKjYNPW

Comment: Maybe you should try a tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

Comment: It didn't helped me much.

Comment: It's still not working...

Comment: as I can see in your form, you have two `<form>` tags that the one having `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute is inside the other one, so maybe this is your problem. remove the first `form` tag and check again.